# Recuperando lista de objetos desatualizadas com Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Quando insiro manualmente um objeto no MySQL via terminal, o Hibernate não recupera a lista com o objeto atualizado, fica sempre igual o da ultima consulta, como se pegasse de algum cache.

Já tentei fazer isso mas não resolveu

```
  public ArrayList<Praga> listarTodasPragas() {     
        ArrayList<Praga> listaPragas = new ArrayList<>(session.createCriteria(Praga.class).list());
        for(Praga p : listaPragas){
            session.refresh(p);
        }
        return listaPragas;
   }
```

Obs.: A session.close() eu fecho logo após chamando um outro método.

Answer (score 2):

```
public Lits<Praga> listarTodasPragas = new ArrayList<>();

public List<Praga> getListarTodasPragas(){

    if(listarTodasPragas == null){
        return   listarTodasPragas = session.createCriteria(Praga.class).list());
    }
    return  listarTodasPragas;
}
```

Comment: seja bem vindo ao StackOverflow em Português, seria ideal que você explicasse sua solução e também formatasse o seu código, para formatar o código basta dar 4 espaços antes de cada linha, ou então selecionar o código e clicar no botão que tem duas chaves { }.

Comment: Não é bem esse meu problema, e essa condição  nunca vai ser TRUE

Comment: quando você carregar a pagina em questão sera chama o getListarTodasPragas.

Answer (score 0):

Você está fazendo o refresh de cada objeto `Praga`, isso faz com que um determinado objeto seja atualizado com o estado dos seus atributos no banco de dados, mas não faz com que todos os objetos daquele tipo sejam atualizados, tampouco fará com que seja resgatada da base uma nova entidade inserida por outro processo.

Uma opção é invocar o método `clear()` da sessão, fazendo assim com que todas as entidades sejam destachadas, de modo que ao requisitar novamente as entidades, a sessão vai buscá-las do banco de dados e não do cache.

Exemplo:

```
  public ArrayList<Praga> listarTodasPragas() {     

        session.clear(); // desatacha todas as entidades da sessão

        ArrayList<Praga> listaPragas = new ArrayList<>(session.createCriteria(Praga.class).list());
        return listaPragas;
   }
```

**Considere as implicações disso no seu sistema:** todas as entidades serão desatachadas. Se houver alteraçoes pendentes no contexto, estas alterações não serão persistidas na base de dados. De modo que provavelmente este não é o melhor jeito de fazer. Talvez o processo invocador de `listarTodasPragas`, aquele quem criou a sessão, é quem deva limpá-la.

Comment: Ok caffé eu havia usado o clear, mas usei ele depois de receber a lista, assim que der posto os resultados. Obrigado. vou testar essa solução